# How to tell which C++ redistributable to include in InstallShield installer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, installshield, vcredist

I have a C# application which uses a C++ DLL, both of which I wrote. The C++ DLL is compiled using the v120 (Visual Studio 2013) Toolset. Which redistributables do I need to include in my InstallShield installer to make this function?

There is no option for a VS2013 redistributable package, only various VS2012 packages and two for VS2015.

A few of the (unhelpfully named) options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBI70.jpg

Comment: You need whatever one includes MSVCR120.dll. You could just include that DLL with your program, in the install folder, rather than using the redistributable installer. EDIT: To be safe, use all of the `msvc*120*.dll` files, though you can probably skip the ones where the non-extension part ends in "d"; those are for debug, and you hopefully compiled for release.

Comment: You can and **must** skip those ending in D. Debug DLL's are not licensed for distribution.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply!

I know I need that set of DLLs, however the options in the InstallShield configuration don't offer any options by toolset number, nor any options named "VS2013" or the like. A few of the likely options I'm confronted with are shown in this screenshot: http://imgur.com/VuDNdNt

Comment: Have you tried to msmually install the redistributable on your pc and see if it pops up in the dialogue?

Comment: Installing which redistributable? That's the problem, I don't know which one to install.

Comment: @CBHacking Please don't suggest actions taken at random without knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get required redistributable from installed VS2013 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\1033). Then in InstallShield you have to execute custom command (redistr_exe with parameters /q /norestart)

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to tell this.  Add the dlls which are included in the c++  redistributables  and it will automatically add the merge modules instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following (x86).prq file of Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable in Installshield install path. In mine it is (C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015LE\SetupPrerequisites).
http://pastebin.com/Yu5DM0kJ

After that open Installshield project, in redistributables you will see Visual C++ 2013 x86. You can do the same to add x64 also.